# Java: URL redirection via tomcat and nginx

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, redirect, nginx

I have a servlet project that is deployed under a `tomcat/webapps/` directory and then I configured tomcat under `nginx` as below:

```
server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:<port>;
        server_name example.com;
        return 302 http://$host$request_uri;
        location / {
          root /home/usr/tomcat/webapps/my_project;
          proxy_pass        http://localhost:8080;
          proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        }
}
```

This is how I want the redirection:

`http://example.com` => `http://example.com/en/` but this is not working with the above configuration and I think this is because nginx append the `302` at begining of the url.
This is what I get from `curl`:

`curl -I 'http://localhost:880/my_project'`

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=<ID>; Path=/my_project/; HttpOnly
Location: http://localhost:8080/my_project/en/
Content-Type: text/html;charset=EUC-KR
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 21 Aug 2013 14:32:34 GMT
```

Now If I want to browse `http://example.com` I get page not found message due to of the redirection.
But if I browse `http://example.com/en` then it works fine; any idea?

Comment: i have 2 questions, what's the 302 redirect for, wouldn't it like cancel the proxy and location and every thing, second question, what's port 9000 for ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady: `302` is there to see if we get a URL found redirection and then redirect it to the right URL, `9000` is a typing mistake here, this should be `8080`, I updated the post.